# Pandas combinations of Dataframe and series

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3,4],
    'B': [12,23,34,45]
})
```

It looks like

```
----------------------------
index         A        B
0             1       12
1             2       23
2             3       34
3             4       45
-----------------------------
```

I have an array of times, `[0,1,2]`. I'd like to make `df` copy rows A and B for each time:

```
------------------------------------
index         A        B     time
              1       12       0
              1       12       1
              1       12       2
              2       23       0
              2       23       1
              2       23       2
              3       34       0
              3       34       1
              3       34       2
              4       45       0
              4       45       1
              4       45       2
-------------------------------------
```

I don't want to use MultiIndex or Stack (since I'd like it as flat as possible). Combine doesn't help. I'm not joining, since I'm trying to make combinations, so Merge/Concatenate seem to not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe using`pd.concat` is slightly faster than `reindex`

```
pd.concat([df]*len([0,1,2])).sort_index().assign(time=[0,1,2]*len(df))
Out[275]: 
   A   B  time
0  1  12     0
0  1  12     1
0  1  12     2
1  2  23     0
1  2  23     1
1  2  23     2
2  3  34     0
2  3  34     1
2  3  34     2
3  4  45     0
3  4  45     1
3  4  45     2
```

Comment: @RafaelC thank you for sharing the timing :-) vote for u :-)

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, use `reindex` +`repeat`

```
o = df.shape[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(times))).reset_index(drop=True)
df['time'] = times*o

    A   B   time
0   1   12  0
1   1   12  1
2   1   12  2
3   2   23  0
4   2   23  1
5   2   23  2
6   3   34  0
7   3   34  1
8   3   34  2
9   4   45  0
10  4   45  1
11  4   45  2
```

---

Performance checking:

```
%timeit df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(times))).reset_index(drop=True).assign(time=times*df.shape[0])
675 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.concat([df]*len([0,1,2])).sort_index().assign(time=[0,1,2]*len(df))
812 µs ± 6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

for small dfs, and

```
%timeit df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(times))).reset_index(drop=True).assign(time=times*df.shape[0])
237 ms ± 3.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.concat([df]*len([0,1,2])).sort_index().assign(time=[0,1,2]*len(df))
5.78 ms ± 27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

for big dfs